# Error creating bean with name 'commandGateway' defined in class path resource [org/axonframework/springboot/autoconfig/AxonAutoConfiguration.class]

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, cqrs, axon, saga

Before I added `spring-data-start-jpa` and `h2-database` dependencies, it was throwing these errors.
I allowed Axon's auto-configuration to do its thing.

Here's the stack trace I got:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'postProductsController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setCommandGateway' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'commandGateway' defined in class path resource [org/axonframework/springboot/autoconfig/AxonAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'commandGateway' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'axonServerCommandBus' defined in class path resource [org/axonframework/springboot/autoconfig/AxonServerAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'axonServerCommandBus' parameter 2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'commandBus' defined in class path resource [org/axonframework/springboot/autoconfig/AxonAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'commandBus' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.axonframework.spring.config.AxonConfiguration': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.axonframework.config.Configurer' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.axonframework.config.Configurer': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.resolveMethodArguments(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:767) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:719) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at 
    ... 77 common frames omitted
```

Here is a sample controller I have created:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/api/v1/products")
public class PostProductsController {

    private  CommandGateway commandGateway;

    @Autowired
    public void setCommandGateway(CommandGateway commandGateway) {
        this.commandGateway = commandGateway;
    }

    @PostMapping
    public String createProduct(@RequestBody CreateProductRestModel createProductRestModel){

        CreateProductCommand createProductCommand = CreateProductCommand.builder()
                .price(createProductRestModel.getPrice())
                .quantity(createProductRestModel.getQuantity())
                .title(createProductRestModel.getTitle())
                .productId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .build();

        String returnValue;

        try{
            returnValue = commandGateway.sendAndWait(createProductCommand);
        } catch (Exception e){
            returnValue = e.getLocalizedMessage();
        }
        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

After I added the dependencies, it started throwing these errors:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.beforeSingletonCreation(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:355) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:227) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isSingleton(AbstractBeanFactory.java:463) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.axonframework.spring.config.AbstractAnnotationHandlerBeanPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAnnotationHandlerBeanPostProcessor.java:73) ~[axon-spring-4.5.4.jar:4.5.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:455) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1808) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730) ~[spring-boot-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412) ~[spring-boot-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302) ~[spring-boot-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) ~[spring-boot-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1290) ~[spring-boot-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at com.mrdiipo.productsservice.ProductsServiceApplication.main(ProductsServiceApplication.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
```

And here is my `application.properties` file:

```
server.port = 0

spring.application.name=products-service
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone= http://localhost:8761/eureka
eureka.instance.instanceid=${spring.application.name}:${instanceId:${random.value}}

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/products;AUTO_SERVER=true
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=XXXXX
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.h2.console.enabled=true

spring.datasource.generate-unique-name= false
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console

spring.h2.console.settings.web-allow-others=true
```

Comment: Do you have a config class where you configure your entityManagerFactory? Please provide some code, i guess you may work with the @Lazy Annotation. Or do you want to use autowired resources when the process is not finished, e. g. in the main method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most important thing to know here is which version of Spring Boot you are using which I could see from the stacktrace: 2.6.0.

This version, released somewhere this week, added an additional check which can explain what you are experiencing and can be found [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.6-Release-Notes#circular-references-prohibited-by-default).

Quoting them:

> #### Circular References Prohibited by Default
>
> Circular references between beans are now prohibited by default. If your application fails to start due to a BeanCurrentlyInCreationException you are strongly encouraged to update your configuration to break the dependency cycle. If you are unable to do so, circular references can be allowed again by setting spring.main.allow-circular-references to true, or using the new setter methods on SpringApplication and SpringApplicationBuilder This will restore 2.5’s behaviour and automatically attempt to break the dependency cycle.

From Axon side, we are already working on that and you the PR to fix this can be found [here](https://github.com/AxonFramework/AxonFramework/pull/2013).
After that is merged, you can expect a minor release with this fix but feel free to follow Spring's advise on how to fix that yourself if you need.

KR,

Comment: Woow!! It worked like magic after hours of debugging. I followed spring's advice. I added "spring.main.allow-circular-references=true" to my application.properties file. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 1):

for spring boot 2.6.2 or higher, use axon 4.5.8 or higher and your issue will be gone.

```
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.axonframework</groupId>
     <artifactId>axon-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.8</version>
 </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Question is not understandable, please share more code with us to get detail answers.
It seems like your two classes is dependent. As mdh mentioned in the comments, @Lazy can solve your problem.

```
@Autowired @Lazy
private Class class;
```

For more: https://www.baeldung.com/circular-dependencies-in-spring

Comment: Thank you very much sir. To be honest with you, the error is somewhat surprising. This error started when I added spring-data-jpa and h2-database. Before I added those dependencies, it was throwing an error from axon commandGateway. I would add the error from axon soon.